# Getting an exception when trying to get the content of a file from response Web API2 WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, asp.net-web-api

Um trying to read the content of a file from a  response as follows

```
 string versionString = await VML.Client.GetStringAsync(new Uri("http://localhost:49454/latest.txt"));
```

File resides in the web api solution and it can be accessible if I type the above URI in the browser

```
 Um getting the following error
```

> Response status code does not indicate success: 406 (Not Acceptable).

How may I fix this issue ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed Via adding

```
 Client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("text/plain"));
```